# Relative primality is primitive recursive

Tags: computability, primitive-recursion

How do I prove that the predicate $P(x , y)$ is primitive recursive, where $P(x,y)$ holds if $x,y$ are relatively prime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two numbers $x,y$ are *not* relatively prime iff there exists some common factor $a > 1$, which divides both $x$ and $y$. This common factor can be bounded by $a$. Therefore $x,y$ are not relatively prime iff there exist $a,b \leq x$ and $c \leq y$ such that (i) $a \geq 2$, (ii) $x = ab$, and (iii) $y = ac$.